# How do i notify a chef execute resource that require a parameter

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to notify the below execute resource from within a remote_file resource and need to pass application name. How do i do it?

```
execute "rm -rf /opt/app/#{application['name']}.zip" do 
  action: nothing
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides that you could use the directory resource to delete it, there is no such thing as a parameter. The resource name is `execute[rm -rf /opt/app/#{application['name']}.zip]` in your case and you have to notify it using this name:

```rb
some_resource "foo" do
  whatever true
  notifies :run, "execute[rm -rf /opt/app/#{application['name']}.zip]"
end
```

For an application with name `test`, the resource name would be `execute[rm -rf /opt/app/test.zip]`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, you can give a resource a more compact name:

```
execute 'delete_files' do
  command "rm -rf /opt/app/#{application['name']}.zip"
  action :nothing
end

some_resource 'foo' do
  whatever true
  notifies :run, 'execute[delete_files]'
end
```